# Cannot install `git-in-zsh` with zplug

Tags: zsh

I am trying to install `git-in-zsh` with zplug but it didn't work at all. This is the line I used for getting the `.zsh` from `git/git`

```sh
zplug "git/git", use:"contrib/completion/*.zsh
```

The file I want to get is in this directory:

https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion

What have I done wrong with `zplug`? How can I source that file?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but: To get Git completion in Zsh, you don't need to install anything. Zsh comes with excellent native completion for Git. All you need to do is put `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit` in your Zsh file and you're good to go.